# How do I get the language code in the product price amount template file?

Tags: magento2, php, template, phtml, language

How can I get the current language code in `Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml`?

Answer (score 0):

Create an after plugin on `\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool::createAmountRender`  and pass currency as a Data value to Block.

**Declare di.xml**

**app/code/{VendorName}/{ModulePath}/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="StackExchange_MagentoModule_Plugin_Frontend_Magento_Framework_Pricing_Render_RendererPool" sortOrder="10" type="StackExchange\MagentoModule\Plugin\Frontend\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Plugin Class:**

**app/code/{VendorName}/{ModulePath}/Plugin/Frontend/Magento/Framework/Pricing/Render/RendererPool.php**

**Code:**

```
<?php

namespace StackExchanges\MagentoModule\Plugin\Frontend\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render;

use Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBoxRenderInterface;

class RendererPool
{

    /**
     * @var Resolver
     */
    private $resolver;

    public function __construct(Resolver $resolver)
    {
        $this->resolver = $resolver;
    }
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        if ($result instanceof  PriceBoxRenderInterface) {
            $result->setData('lang_code',$this->resolver->getLocale());
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Then on `default.phtml` , you can get the current language code using

`$block->getLangCode();`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, where did you declared the getLangCode method?

Comment: Asc $result->setData('lang_code',$this->resolver->getLocale()); using code that why lang_code converted to a setter function `getLangCode`